# Continuous function preserving rational difference.

Tags: real-analysis

> Find all the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $f(x)-f(y)\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Can somebody give me some hint to solve this problem. I think that the functions are $f(x)=mx+b$ where $m\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the function $\vartheta (y) =f(x+y) -f(y) $ this function is continuous and maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ hence $\vartheta $ is constant equal to $c$. Hence $$ c=f(x) -f(0)$$ and therefore $$f(x) -f(0) =f(x+y) -f(y)$$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{R}.$ Now let $(z,y)\in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and let $z_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $z_n \to z $ then $$f(z_n ) -f(0) -f(z_n +y) +f(y) \to 0$$ and by the continuity of $f$ $$f(z_n ) -f(0) -f(z_n +y) +f(y) \to f(z) -f(0) -f(z+y) +f(y) $$ hence $$f(z) -f(0) -f(z+y) +f(y)=0 $$ for all $(z,y)\in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}.$ Thus $f(t) =at +b $ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R} $ but now it is easy to observe that $a$ must be rational.

Comment: Don't you have a mistake in the third equation? An equal instead of a $\rightarrow$?

Comment: If $a_n =0$ then of course $a_n \to 0$