# Rational Function

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is,

Find all continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
if $x-y$ is rational, $f(x)-f(y)$ is rational.

I was thinking that only constant functions would work. How would I prove this??

Comment: Certainly more than constant functions work; for instance, any affine transformation works.

Comment: @neth: Isn't $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}x$ an affine transformation that doesn't work?

Comment: @Bungo: sorry, you're right. Any affine transformation with rational coefficients.

Comment: A good starting point is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167620/functions-that-take-rationals-to-rationals and maybe some other questions listed under "Related".

Comment: Certainly all linear functions with rational coefficients would work. But I was looking for group of functions that satisfy the given condition, without any extra conditions for the coefficients.

Comment: What is a "group"? They **do** form a group in the sense of [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory); apparently, you mean it in some other sense. What is it?

Comment: Yes they would but I didn't mean the mathematical 'group'. I meant something like 'set of linear functions', 'set of exponential function' etc.

Comment: I found the answer here. [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004280/continuos-function-preserving-rational-difference?rq=1)

Comment: @zxcvber Yes. This should be closed as duplicate.